# What is the default cache strategy when using Redis with spring or spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, distributed-caching

There are various cache strategies like: Cache Aside, Read Through, Write Through, Write Behind, Write Around.

When Redis is used with spring boot using `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` dependency, what is the default Cache Strategy.   And how can this be changed. Any reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: few use full links on redis: https://programmerfriend.com/ultimate-guide-to-redis-cache-with-spring-boot-2-and-spring-data-redis/ and https://medium.com/@MatthewFTech/spring-boot-cache-with-redis-56026f7da83a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, you get cache aside, our cache usage in the Spring boot app looks something similar to this

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "someCache")
public String cacheThis(String id){
    return "this Is it";
}
```

In most of the scenarios in the spring boot app, we cache the result of JPA or other DB queries. In such cases, we add `Cacheable` on the query method, which gives us cache aside feature.

> An application can emulate the functionality of read-through caching
> by implementing the cache-aside strategy. This strategy loads data
> into the cache on demand.

[image: Cache Aside]

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cache-aside

Using cache aside pattern is not the always solution to a problem, depending on your use case you might have to change the caching strategy. Changing caching strategy is not straight forward except some annotations we know from the Spring framework like

- Cacheable
- CacheEvict
- CachePut

You need to update your application code to use other caching strategies, though you can build any caching strategy using these annotations. If you don't like to use these annotations then play with the actual cache object, at any time you can call Cache methods to modify the cache.

eg

```
Cache myCache = cacheManager.getCache("myCache");
```

Once you have a cache object, you can call all relevant methods, some methods may not work as expected due to the limitation of the underlying cache.

Comment: cool explanation +1. I have one another Q (probably last) - [How to enable distributed/clustered cache when using redis with spring data cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63976941/how-to-enable-distributed-clustered-cache-when-using-redis-with-spring-data-cach)